# Android GoogleMap Error

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently, I am using google map api V2 to display map into my app by using **"com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView"**. My problem is that when particular device doesn't have "google play services" install then automatically **"Get Google Play services"** button will display withing "MapView". But when i click on that button app is forced closed with error **"No Activity found to handle Intent{act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms}"** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
try{
     put your code here to open Google Play services
   }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      show some text here
    }
```

Comment: But it just handles your exception to avoid force close app. I want to display google map which must require "Google Play Services" to be installed. Plz suggest me another way if possible to load map into app which doesn't depend on "Google Play Services".